# Open a NEC binary in Ghidra

Tags: disassembly, firmware, ghidra, firmware-analysis

I have a binary dump from a 76F0219F1 NEC processor. I tried to open it in Ghidra, but I don't see any NEC in the list of supported processors.
Does Ghidra support NEC processors? Is there anything I can do to open the NEC binary dump in Ghidra?

Comment: Probably unsupported but what CPU core is that? 78K, V850, something else?

Comment: @Igor, its an automotive MCU on V850 core. Unfortunately, such processors not documented well...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything I can do to open the NEC binary dump in Ghidra?

Yes. If Ghidra does not currently support 76F0219F1 NEC processor architecture, Ghidra can be extended using [SLEIGH](https://ghidra.re/courses/languages/html/sleigh.html). Here are some examples of how to do this:

- [Implementing a New CPU Architecture for Ghidra](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1b955DV2ii-Dgv6YR4kUrJtjGugEqXD3FffTHRfvVSYo/edit#slide=id.g4525dccad7_0_0)
- [new 6502 CPU description](https://github.com/tom-seddon/Ghidra6502)
- [Writing a wasm loader for Ghidra. Part 1: Problem statement and setting up environment](https://m.habr.com/en/post/443318/)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for this

Comment: @Ruturaj you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately not. Look at [this](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#what-processors-are-currently-supported) question, among the frequently asked questions.

According to that:

> X86 16/32/64, ARM/AARCH64, PowerPC 32/64/VLE, MIPS 16/32/64/micro,
>   68xxx, Java / DEX bytecode, PA-RISC, PIC 12/16/17/18/24, Sparc 32/64,
>   CR16C, Z80, 6502, 8051, MSP430, AVR8, AVR32 and the variants of these
>   processors

are currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

I'm uploaded some scratches to https://github.com/esaulenka/ghidra_v850

Currently it not usable, but any help are welcome!